# How to use BERT in image caption tasks,such as im2txt,densecap

Tags: nlp, computer-vision

Preparing to use Bert Before refining downstream tasks, let's start with a few general questions about NLP, saying that this is to emphasize Bert's universality. In general, most NLP problems fall into the four types of tasks shown in the figure above:

One type is sequence labeling. This is the most typical NLP task. For example, Chinese word segmentation, part-of-speech tagging, named entity recognition, semantic role tagging, etc. can be classified into this type of problem. It is characterized by the requirement of each word in the sentence model. The context must give a classification category.

The second category is classification tasks, such as our common text classification, emotional calculations, etc. can be classified into this category. It is characterized by the fact that no matter how long the article is, it is generally given a classification category.

The third type of task is sentence relationship judgment. For example, Entailment, QA, semantic rewriting, natural language reasoning and other tasks are all this model. Its characteristic is that given two sentences, the model judges whether two sentences have some semantic relationship.

The fourth category is generative tasks, such as machine translation, text summaries, writing poems, reading pictures, and so on. It is characterized by the need to generate another piece of text autonomously after entering the text content.

The first three tasks are very common, and now I want to do the image caption task in the fourth task.My normal implementation is based on densecap:[A Hierarchical Approach for Generating Descriptive Image Paragraphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06607). [the code is here](https://github.com/Wentong-DST/im2p/blob/master/HRNN_paragraph_batch.py)

Comment: There is this https://github.com/ajamjoom/Image-Captions

Comment: Excuse me . I have the features from the images in a file .pkl and need to apply BERT for the caption generation but the code I couldn't replace my features with its features as I couldn't find features file . Can you help me how can I go in this code ?